# ASP.net Treeview/Listview combination or alternative

Tags: asp.net, listview, treeview

I need to create an ASP.net page that has a control on the page that has a five-level TreeView on the left side of the page, and accounting balances on the right side the coincide with each breakdown in the tree. Top level is company, next is group, next is program, etc... and the balances break down accordingly.

I've seen that there are controls out there such as TreeView/ListView combination controls that can do this. Can I accomplish this without paying for controls?

Could a treeview do this alone by spanning data across the entire length of the columns since every level will have totals on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply structured the SQL, and looped through the results, creating divs of varying length to produce the result.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you and I was not paying for controls. I would use jquery and find some pre built trees and grids. A quick Google search brings up [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/demo/basic_html) for the tree view. I would try it out. It looks like you just give it bunch of nested ul and li tags. For the right side of your page I would try out [flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/). It looks like it could get the job done. If you happen to be using MVC I would check out the [Telerik MVC controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx) they are free.

If I am not you and paying for controls I am using [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com) or [ComponentArt](http://www.componentart.com/). They are well worth the cost.